# Service that runs once when ppp0 connection shows up

Tags: debian, systemd, ppp, wvdial

We use `wvdial` to initiate a cell modem connection. We wrap it with `nohup`, launched by a `cron` job that checks if all is well every minute (everything we read said that wvdial and the associated hardware is unreliable enough that you want something like the cron job to watchdog it).

When that network comes alive (always seems to show up as `ppp0` from `ifconfig`), we want to do some work, such as run `ntpdate` and some `rsync` operations. Is there anyway to configure a service that runs each time there is a new and established `ppp0` connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "/etc/ppp/ip-up" to add programs that run once the interface is up. I have work with it several times and it works. You could also use "/etc/ppp/ip-down" in case you need to run programs once the connection is over.